# flutter error app:processDebugResources. how to solve?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

hi everyone hope everyone is well. i am new to flutter and while building my application for my final year project i came accross this issue..my application is working on ios emulator but when i plug it into my andriod phone i come across this issue please advise

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/Desktop/c3mobiredo/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:44: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.c3mobiredo:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

```
 ERROR:/Users/Desktop/c3mobiredo/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:50: AAPT: error: resource style/LaunchTheme (aka com.example.c3mobiredo:style/LaunchTheme) not found.

 ERROR:/Users/Desktop/c3mobiredo/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:65: AAPT: error: resource style/NormalTheme (aka com.example.c3mobiredo:style/NormalTheme) not found.
```

please let me know if you need additional information from me

Answer (score 0):

It's about files not being found. Does the android folder in your project have a structure like this? [image]